# SQL: How to check for each unique value in one column how many combinations of another column can be found

Tags: sql

Working in SSMS. Based on a value in one column I want to count the number of different occurrences in another column. How would I go about to do that?

Basically for each unique value in Column 1, how many combinations of Column 2 can be found?

So if table looks like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

Desired output would then be:

A = 1

B = 3

C = 2

Answer (score 2):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for this case with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Col1, COUNT(DISTINCT Col2)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Col1
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d50d9ffeaea79e0ec78edbdfb36eba63)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(Column1,Column2) AS
(

  SELECT 'A',   1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' ,  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' ,  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' ,  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' ,  2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' ,  3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  3
)
SELECT C.COLUMN1,COUNT(DISTINCT C.COLUMN2)CNTT
 FROM CTE AS C
 GROUP BY C.Column1
```

CTE is an example you provided. Please replace reference to it with reference to your table